# A year with eight Sh'minis is plenteous?

Tags: number, calendar, sources-mekorot, segulah, parashat-shemini

I've heard an idea that a year (like 5772) in which *parashas Sh'mini* is read eight times<sup>[1]</sup> is a particularly auspicious one: the wording of the maxim is something like "*sh'mona Sh'mini sh'mena*" ([a year with] eight *Sh'mini*s is fat [=plenteous]). Does anyone know the provenance, wording, or meaning of this maxim/idea?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This occurs in *chutz laaretz* (only) in a year in which *Pesach* starts on the *Shabas* after *Shabas parashas Tzav*. In that case, *Sh'mini* is read the afternoon of *Shabas hagadol*, the following Monday and Thursday, the afternoons of the first and eighth days of *Pesach*, the following Monday and Thursday, and the *Shabas* morning after *Pesach*.

Comment: see this letter from the Lubavitcher Rebbe - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15944&st=&pgnum=309 - (referenced in the source in @jutky's answer) - where the Rebbe says this is a saying that is often recited by Polish Chassidim (referring to non-Chabad chassidim). The Rebbe then explains it according to Chassidus. The Correct saying is "Shmini Shmonah, Shmeina".

Comment: @Menachem, thanks (and to you, jutky), but I still wonder about its provenance. That it comes from some Polish _chasid_ (or, especially, that it comes from some non-Lubavitch _chasid_) is very little source information.

Comment: The Rebbe talks about it in Igros too: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/admur/ig/1/149

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=9099 good quote about this.  I honestly don't know if you'll find a good source for this saying, though.  Good luck!

Comment: rabbi moshe shternbuch reportedly said that he has this as a kabbala from the gr"a

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_16015_145.pdf) is the hisvaadus that presents this idea (in seif yud). Found by googling so I can't provide any additional information.

> ‫ובזה גופא — קוראים פ׳ שמיני‬
>   ‫שמונה פעמים. וכמדובר פעם הפתגם‬
>   ‫בזה מחסידי פולין: שמיני שמונה‬
>   ‫שמנה, כלומר, ששנה שקוראים בה פ׳‬
>   ‫שמיני שמונה פעמים — תהי׳ שנה‬
>   ‫״שמנה״.‬

Comment: [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/16015) is the volume it's from if that is what you were getting at.