# Weekday Torah reading the same for two weeks when Yom Tov falls on Shabbat?

Tags: calendar, torah-reading

When Yom Tov falls on Shabbat, superseding the regular weekly Torah portion, does the Monday and Thursday weekday reading stay the same the week before and the week after the holiday? E.g., this year, 2016, in חו"ל, is the the portion of 'Aharey Mot' read on the Monday and Thursday of the week before Passover and then again on the Monday and Thursday of the week after Passover?

Comment: In Israel they will read Acharei Mot before the week after Passover. Note as well that the readings at Shabbat Mincha over the holiday are affected as well. IAE what else do you think the reading would be if not the next Parsha?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I assume that it will always be the next parshah, I'm just asking for confirmation. I wasn't able to find a calendar online that lists Monday/Thursday readings explicitly (and I have to prepare leining, so don't want to make a mistake and prepare the wrong parsha).

Comment: Then yes I can confirm for you, the reading at M/T and Saturday Mincha is that of the next full Parsha to be read, in this case, Acharei Mot. It might not be trivial to find a formal source for that.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15857

Answer (score 2):

The 2 possible Shabbat parshi'ot that can be read the most are Shmini (non-leap year) and Acharei Mot (leap year, as in this year). Both can be read a max of 8 times, exactly because of what you have stated in your question. Note that this only occurs in Diaspora. This leaves Diaspora one week behind Israel for a while.

This year, the "evening" week, I believe, is Matot-Mas'ei.

Actually, this phenomenon happens for an even longer period that stretches out for 3 weeks if you assume that Shabbat mincha is the start of a "new week". Here's how. When Rosh Hashanna occurs on Thurs. Fri. (which is the same 2 day length in both Israel and Diaspora), Vezot Habracha is read a total of 7 times:

**Week 1**

- Shabbat Shuva mincha
- Monday
- Thursday

The following Shabbat mincha is Yom Kippur, so it's skipped! It's the only occasion where the weekly parsha is skipped on Shabbat Mincha

**Week 2**

- Monday

**Week 3**

- Shabbat mincha on Hol Hamo'ed Succot
- Thursday night for Simchat Torah night
- Friday morning on SImchat Torah

Comment: IINM a few communities in the diaspora have a custom to read _Sh'mini Atezeres_ night. I assume (but don't know for certain) that what they read is _V'zos hab'racha_. That'd make eight.

Comment: @msh210 It would. I don't know of anyone that actually reads Torah on Shmini Atzeret. If you know of any, please provide link or info. Happy Pesach to you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the quip that Shmini is read eight times when Pesach in Chutz La'aretz has the first and last day on Shabbas in a non leap year (so that Shmini is the parsha affected). Mincha, Mon, Thurs, Mincha, (skip Chol HaMoed ), Mincha, Mon, Thur, Shabbos.

This is a well known riddle that children bring home when it happens.

[In 1991](http://www.meaningfullife.com/torah/eight-times-eight/) for example

> This year, both the first and last days of Passover fall on Shabbat.
>   As a result, the section of Shemini is twice “postponed” and is
>   publicly read in the synagogue eight times over the course of three
>   weeks: on the Shabbat afternoon, Monday and Thursday before Passover;
>   on the afternoon of the first day of Passover; on the afternoon of the
>   last day of Passover; on the Monday, Thursday and Shabbat mornings the
>   week after Passover.
>
> So this year, the lesson of Shemini is even more compelling than in
>   other years. It is read eight times, granting us the power of eight,
>   eight times over.
>
> Based on an address by the Rebbe, Shabbat Shemini 5751 (April 13,
>   1991) Sefer HaSichot 5751, vol. II, pp. 475-477.